# SQL Server 2019 unable to get Pagination to work correctly with UNION

Tags: sql-server, pagination, union, offset

```
    SELECT * FROM 
           (SELECT IdNumber from LegacyTable 
           WHERE IdNumber != 0 
           ORDER BY IdNumber 
           OFFSET 0 ROWS 
           FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
       
           UNION 
           SELECT IdNumber FROM Customer 
           WHERE IdNumber != '0' 
           ORDER BY IdNumber 
           OFFSET 0 ROWS 
           FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY) as Customers 
    ORDER BY IdNumber 
    OFFSET 0 ROWS 
    FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

I have two tables in my database. One Table contains legacy customer data and the other one is when a new customer signs up. I want to get all rows from BOTH tables but use offset/take for pagination.

If I don't paginate, the query works but it takes a VERY LONG TIME.
I am new to SQL Server but I've read that Pagination should help resolve the problem.

The above code gives me 10 records. However if I change the value of the OFFSET to 10, it ends up skipping rows.

If there is a better way, please let me know.

---

LegacyTable

```
CREATE TABLE LegacyTable (
    IdNumber INT,
    FirstName VARCHAR(40),
    LastName VARCHAR(40)
)
```

CustomerTable

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
    IdNumber INT,
    FirstName VARCHAR(40),
    LastName VARCHAR(40)
)
```

The Legacy Table has 40 additional fields which was used by the mainframe application. I didnt list it here.

Comment: I'll repeat what i said on your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66028069/2029983), as you *still* haven't provided it... *"Sample data, and expected results, and a [mre] of the unexpected behaviour will help us help you."*

Comment: You've "read that pagination solves the problem", Firstly that is not true most of the time due to other issues in the query besides size of data. Secondly you obviously don't get all the rows if you paginate, what did you expect? You need to be clear, do you want *all* the data, or do you want to paginate? If you [edit] to include the table definitions and sample data, maybe we can help.

Comment: @Charlieface my application will need all the data but instead of loading 100,000 at once. I just need to get a smaller subset of the data. As the user needs to go to the next page, i'd request the next set of data.

I honestly don't see how a list of #'s is going to be helpful. But sure why not! 
Do you need all 100,000 records or is a sample of the data enough?

Comment: A sample, just a few rows, you can put in fake data if it bothers you. And the table definitions `CREATE TABLE...`. So you need to paginate? Are you paginating the final union or also the two tables first (not sure why you would do that)? Do you need a `UNION` (distinct rows, will be slow) or `UNION ALL` (just merge results without checking duplicates)?

Comment: @Charlieface thats whats happening, the performance from the query is so slow. It takes ages to get a result set. I am not deadset on paginate or anything. I am trying to get data from these two tables. The data between the two tables should be different but a legacy customer can headover to the website and sign up (again) and then we would have her once in the new table and once in the old table.

Comment: @Charlieface i added the Table DDL. My SQL Server is being updated by the DBA team so it's offline and I can't run queries to get an image of the sample data.

Comment: Which offset do you want to change, or why do you have an offset on the inner tables? Also, does `UNION ALL` speed it up? When your server is back up, please also share a query plan via https://pastetheplan.com

Comment: @Charlieface TBH I am still learning so I was trying different things until something worked. However after spending a week on this problem, I was hoping someone who has had a similar problem would be able to enlighten me or share their query.

But what I was hoping for was to get all the data in sets of 10 as if I was paginating 1 table.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue appears to be that you are using `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`. This means that *all* the inner tables need to be fully evaluated for de-duplication before moving on to the outer query.

Putting an `OFFSET` on the inner tables also is going to mess up the results, for obvious reasons.

You could just put it on them, and get 10 rows for each table, but another option is to use `UNION ALL`, which can process rows without blocking.

I note that you are using `!= '0'` on the second table, I would assume this is an `int` column, so you want to use a number here, not text:

```sql
  SELECT * FROM 
           (SELECT IdNumber from LegacyTable 
           WHERE IdNumber != 0 
       
           UNION ALL

           SELECT IdNumber FROM Customer 
           WHERE IdNumber != 0 
           
    ) as Customers 
    ORDER BY IdNumber 
    OFFSET 0 ROWS 
    FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```